# Fetching all the document URI's in MarkLogic Using Java Client API

Tags: java, marklogic

i am trying to fetch all the documents from a database without knowing the exact url's . I got one query

```
DocumentPage documents =docMgr.read();
while (documents.hasNext()) {
    DocumentRecord document = documents.next();
    System.out.println(document.getUri());
}
```

But i do not have specific urls , i want  all the documents

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? If you want to export the content, MLCP would be easier. If you're looking to do some number crunching, it might be easier to do inside MarkLogic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to enable your uris lexicon on the database.

You could eval some XQuery and run cts:uris() (or server-side JS and run cts.uris()):

```
    ServerEvaluationCall call = client.newServerEval()
        .xquery("cts:uris()");
    for ( EvalResult result : call.eval() ) {
        String uri = result.getString();
        System.out.println(uri);
    }
```

Two drawbacks are: (1) you'd need a user with [privileges](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices#id_70532) and (2) there is no pagination.

If you have a small number of documents, you don't need pagination.  But for a large number of documents pagination is recommended.  Here's some code using the search API and pagination:

```
    // do the next eight lines just once
    String options =
        "<options xmlns='http://marklogic.com/appservices/search'>" +
        "  <values name='uris'>" +
        "    <uri/>" +
        "  </values>" +
        "</options>";
    QueryOptionsManager optionsMgr = client.newServerConfigManager().newQueryOptionsManager();
    optionsMgr.writeOptions("uriOptions", new StringHandle(options));

    // run the following each time you need to list all uris
    QueryManager queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();
    long pageLength = 10000;
    queryMgr.setPageLength(pageLength);
    ValuesDefinition query = queryMgr.newValuesDefinition("uris", "uriOptions");
    // the following "and" query just matches all documents
    query.setQueryDefinition(new StructuredQueryBuilder().and());
    int start = 1;
    boolean hasMore = true;
    Transaction transaction = client.openTransaction();
    try {
        while ( hasMore ) {
            CountedDistinctValue[] uriValues =
                queryMgr.values(query, new ValuesHandle(), start, transaction).getValues();
            for (CountedDistinctValue uriValue : uriValues) {
                String uri = uriValue.get("string", String.class);
                //System.out.println(uri);
            }
            start += uriValues.length;
            // this is the last page if uriValues is smaller than pageLength
            hasMore = uriValues.length == pageLength;
        }
    } finally {
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

The transaction is only necessary if you need a guaranteed "snapshot" list isolated from adds/deletes happening concurrently with this process.  Since it adds some overhead, feel free to remove it if you don't need such exactness.

Comment: can you tell me if we can specify the collection from which it should fetch the uris?

Comment: You can specify the query using instead of StructuredQueryBuilder.and  with StructuredQueryBuilder.collection https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/query/StructuredQueryBuilder.html#collection%28java.lang.String...%29

Comment: found a better option using this :

    ServerEvaluationCall call =
        client.newServerEval().xquery(
            "for $x in collection(\"RexUserProfiles\") return( fn:document-uri($x) )");

Answer (score 0):

find out the page length and  in the queryMgr you can specify the starting point to access. Keep on increasing the starting point and loop through all the URL. I was able to fetch all URI. This could be not so good approach but works.

```
List<String> uriList = new ArrayList<>();       
        QueryManager queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();
        StructuredQueryBuilder qb = new StructuredQueryBuilder();
        StructuredQueryDefinition querydef = qb.and(qb.collection("xxxx"), qb.collection("whatever"), qb.collection("whatever"));//outputs 241152
        SearchHandle results = queryMgr.search(querydef, new SearchHandle(), 10);
        long pageLength = results.getPageLength();
        long totalResults = results.getTotalResults();
        System.out.println("Total Reuslts: " + totalResults);
        long timesToLoop = totalResults / pageLength;
        for (int i = 0; i < timesToLoop; i = (int) (i + pageLength)) {
            System.out.println("Printing Results from: " + (i) + " to: " + (i + pageLength));
            results = queryMgr.search(querydef, new SearchHandle(), i);
            MatchDocumentSummary[] summaries = results.getMatchResults();//10 results because page length is 10
            for (MatchDocumentSummary summary : summaries) {
//                System.out.println("Extracted friom URI-> " + summary.getUri());
                uriList.add(summary.getUri());
            }
            if (i >= 1000) {//number of URI to store/retreive. plus 10
                break;
            }
        }
         uriList= uriList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        return uriList;
```